# elasticsearch search with/without spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

Good day, I created a searchable index based on phonetics (in Example 2 fields: with indexing on metaphone and ngram). How do I configure the index to not take into account the gaps in sentences like this: "4gb" and "4 gb"?

```
PUT product_name
{
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "number_of_shards": 1,
         "number_of_replicas": 0,
         "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
               "ngram_index": {
                  "tokenizer": "standard",
                  "filter": [
                     "standard",
                     "lowercase",
                     "index_ngram",
                     "stopwords",
                     "synonym"
                  ]
               },

                "meta_index": {
                    "filter":["standard","lowercase","my_metaphone","stopwords", "synonym"],
                      "type":"custom",
                      "tokenizer":"standard"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
               "index_ngram": {
                  "type": "nGram",
                  "min_gram": 3,
                  "max_gram": 15
               },     
               "my_metaphone" : {
                    "type" : "phonetic",
                    "encoder" : "metaphone",
                    "replace" : true
                },
               "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : [
                                                    "i-pod, i pod => ipod",
                        "universe, cosmos",
                        "1, I, i",
                        "2, II, ii",
                        "3, III, iii",
                        "4, IV, iv",
                        "5, V, v",
                        "6, VI, vi",
                        "7, VII, vii",
                        "8, VIII, viii",
                        "9, IX, ix",
                        "10, X, x",
                        "s4, sIV",
                        "4 gb, 4gb"

                    ]
                },
               "stopwords": {
                  "type": "stop",
                  "stopwords": "algúnalguna, algunasЭ
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "products": {
         "properties": {
            "Name": {
               "type": "multi_field",
               "fields": {
                  "Name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "NGram_name": {
                      "type": "string",
                     "index_analyzer": "ngram_index",
                     "search_analyzer": "ngram_index"
                  },
                  "Meta_name": {
                      "type": "string",
                     "index_analyzer": "meta_index",
                     "search_analyzer": "meta_index"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```